# Why is the following proof about an analytic function attaining the maximum on the boundary true?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, maximum-principle

I have the following statement

> Let $D\subset \Bbb{C}$ be a bounded open nonempty subset. Take $\bar D$ to be the closure of $D$. Let $$f:\bar D\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$$be a continuous function which is analytic on $D\subset \bar D$. Then $|f(z)|$ attains the maximum at some point on the boundary of $D$.

I have given the following proof:

> Since $\bar D$ is compact and $|f|$ is continuous we know that $|f|$ attains the maximum $z_0\in \bar D$. Assume $z_0$ is not on the boundary. Then by the maximum principle $f$ is constant. Hence $|f|$ attains the maximum everywhere so also on the boundary which is a contradiction. Thus $z_0$ needs to be on the boundary.

Now I don't see why this prove is correct. I mean in my opinion the maximum principle only tells me that $f$ is constant in $D$. But we have no information about the boundary of $D$? How is it then possible to conclude that the maximum is on the boundary which gives us a contradiction?

Can maybe someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: If $f$ is constant on $D$, then $f$ is constant on $\bar D$, since $f$ is continuous on $\bar D,$

Comment: Think about what values $f$ could have on the boundary of $\bar D$ if it's constant arbitrarily close to it (i.e. on $D$) and continuous.  Say $f(x)\equiv 1$ on $D$ -- how could $f$ get to be $1+\epsilon$ on $\bar D$ without being $1+\epsilon /2$ before reaching $\partial D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is constant on $D$ and continuous on $\bar D$, then it is constant on $\bar D$. Indeeed, if $z\in \bar D$, then there exists a sequence $(z_n)$ in $D$ such that $z_n\to z$. Since $f$ is continuous on $\bar D$, this implies $f(z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=f(z_1)$, where $f(z_1)$ is the constant value of $f$ on $D$. Thus $f$ takes the same value at $z$ as everywhere on $D$.

Comment: Ah I see thank you!

Comment: sorry did I understand it correctly that the existence of such a sequence $z_n$ in $D$ is given since $\bar D$ is compact?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos sorry in my notes $\bar D$ denotes the closure of $D$?

Comment: In your notes and everywhere else.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so could you maybe explain why such a sequence exists?

Comment: The closure of a set $D\subset\Bbb C$ is the set of those $z\in\Bbb C$ which are the limit of some sequence of elements of $D$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant the closure, not boundary.

Comment: To complement José Carlos Santos's comments: Compactness of $\bar D$ is irrelevant for this part of the proof.